# Instantiate scriptableobject with random variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I just started to work with scriptableobject, and I'm trying to Instantiate / Create Instance of a very basic scriptableobject that got 4 line of arrays.

I'm trying to Instantiate one scriptableobject that I created, that every time he's been created he will randomize his variables

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Character",menuName = "Character Creation/Player Units")]
public class CharStats : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string [] charName;
    public string [] charDescription;
    public string [] charSin;
    public Sprite [] charIcon;
}
```

The changing I'm doing do inside the inspector for one scriptableobject, and just his inside variables will change every time I create new one. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Yea it's definitely doable. You'd make an editor tool that creates and serailizes a new object. Make a static array of all of your options, randomize the index that your current object chooses and create it. Your current setup is storing all of the arrays in each object. I wouldn't do that unless you just want a randomized order of your original data in each object. If you'd like an example I can add one.

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment, I would like to see an example, not sure I got the basic idea.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Every object has a constructor. You can always add code to that constructor to call the `Random` class to generate random numbers, and then use those numbers to create random data to your heart's content. What research have you done so far? **What have you tried?** What _specifically_ do you need help with?

Comment: Sure I can add one. Just to clarify, you want to generate a ScriptableObject with a random name, description, sin and sprite icon from lists that you define right? Right now you have a ScriptableObject with arrays for each type, but you most likely only want one of each of these per objects not the entire array right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct ( I can say like image spawning a person with one of which of those variables )

Comment: So you want instances of that ScriptableObject pick random values .. but from which source pool? It makes no sense to have this ScriptableObject and define in there the available options and at the same time pick a random one from them for each instance ... you rather need some kind of common pool where to pick values from. Also unclear: Do the values need to be unique? -> how will you make sure there are enough entries in the common value pool for the amount of instances you will create? And do these actually need to be `ScriptableObject` at all? You want them on runtime or already in editor?

Comment: To add to derHugo's questions, do you want this data to be persistent across all sessions? Meaning once you create one, it is there forever and can be re-used in all instances of your game? Or do you want them randomly created each session so it is different every time you play? Depending on what you want heavily changes how you should go about implementing this. One would be an editor script that generates ScriptableObjects in editor for runtime use while the other is just instantiating GameObjects at runtime.

Comment: Ill posted an update for what I meant, maybe it will clear it out? might be not the right way to use this. and yes, once its been created its stayed as it is unless destroyed. ( it will be able to act like the character in fallout shelter. ( can be clicked on/dragged but stay with the same data)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I manage to create something might be not the right way, but after pressing a key ( for now testing) its Instantiate my scriptableobjectwith a random Icon I put on for now. Ill add the 3 scripts, bad names coz it's for testing only, (testing - its script that sitting on empty gameobject with reference to my scriptableobject, testing 2 - its script that sitting on  a prefab that I Instantiate with the scriptableobject)

```css
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class testing2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public ScriptableObject person;
    public CharStats charSats;

    public Sprite sprite2;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRender;
    private void Start()
    {
        spriteRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        GetRandomSprite();

    }

    public Sprite GetRandomSprite()
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, charSats.charIcon.Length);

        
        Debug.Log(charSats.charIcon[randomIndex]);

        if (sprite2 == null)
        {
            sprite2 = charSats.charIcon[randomIndex];
            spriteRender.sprite = sprite2;

        }
        return charSats.charIcon[randomIndex];
        
    }
}
```

```css
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class Testing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;

    private void Update()
    {
        SpawnPlayer();
    }

    public void SpawnPlayer()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GameObject spawnPalyer = Instantiate(Player, new Vector3(Random.Range(-10,10), Random.Range(-10, 10)), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }

    }


}
```

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Character",menuName = "Character Creation/Player Units")]
public class CharStats : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string [] charName;
    public string [] charDescription;
    public string [] charSin;
    public Sprite [] charIcon;

    
}
```